# Twilio sms api limits from ip

Tags: request, twilio, limit

i'm interested in limitations from one ip till error with multiple Twilio accounts sending requests to the twilio API.
How big is the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Our API concurrency limit is 100 concurrent requests:

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues

Hope that helps.